# Transition from one scene to another scene in animation using OpenGL?

Tags: c++, animation, opengl, glut

I tried to change from one scene to another scene using `glutSwapBuffers()`, but if i run this code, all i can get is a blue background. Can someone help me pinpoint where is the problem and provide simple solution to this problem?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gl\gl.h>
#include <gl\glu.h>
#include <gl\glut.h> 
#include <io.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 10
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 10
#define PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795
#define FPS 30

int x = 30;
int y = 50;
int dx = 10;//velocity
int dy = 15;

int winWidth = 1200, winHeight = 1000, counter = 0;
time_t t;

void init() {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, winWidth, 0.0, winHeight);
}

float elapsedTime = 0, base_time = 0, fps = 0, frames;

void calcFPS() {
    elapsedTime = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    if ((elapsedTime - base_time) > 1000.0) {
        fps = frames * 1000.0 / (elapsedTime - base_time);
        printf("fps: %f", fps);
        base_time = elapsedTime;
        frames = 0;
    }
    frames++;
}

void r_idle() {}

void MyTimerFunc(int value);

/*======================
********INITIALIZE******
*======================*/
void circle(int x, int y, int r);
void rectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3, int x4, int y4);
void triangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3);
void line(float a, float b, float c, float d);
void car();
void road();
void cloud();
void lightning();
void ghost2();
void ghost2_move();

/*======================
********SHAPES**********
*======================*/

void circle(int x, int y, int r) // r = radius
{
    //draw a circle
    float theta;
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++)
    {
        theta = i * PI / 180;
        glVertex2f(x + r * cos(theta), y + r * sin(theta)); //x-axis , y-axis, 196 = radius
    }
    glEnd();
}

void rectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3, int x4, int y4)
{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(x1, y1);
    glVertex2f(x2, y2);
    glVertex2f(x3, y3);
    glVertex2f(x4, y4);
    glEnd();
}

void triangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3)
{
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2f(x1, y1);
    glVertex2f(x2, y2);
    glVertex2f(x3, y3);
    glEnd();
}

void line(float a, float b, float c, float d) 
{
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2f(a, b);
    glVertex2f(c, d);
    glEnd();
}

/*===========================
********BACKGROUND**********
*===========================*/
void car()
{
    //upper car body
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.5); //blue
    rectangle(0, 280, 1120, 280, 1400, -140, -560, -140);
    //bottom car body
    rectangle(-840, -140, 1400, -140, 1400, -700, -840, -700);

    //front- window (window 1)
    glColor3f(0.51, 0.47, 0.47); //lightest grey
    triangle(-476, -140, -28, 196, -28, -140);
    rectangle(28, 196, 560, 196, 560, -140, 28, -140);
    rectangle(644, 196, 1120, 196, 1120, -140, 644, -140);

    //wheel
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); //black
    circle(-420, -798, 196); //front wheel
    circle(1036, -798, 196); // back wheel
}

void road()
{
    //road
    glColor3f(0.2, 0.21, 0.2); //light grey
    rectangle(-1400, -980, 1400, -980, 1400, -1400, -1400, -1400);
}

void cloud()
{
    glColor3f(0.17, 0.19, 0.21); //grey
    rectangle(-1400, 1400, 1400, 1400, 1400, 1260, -1400, 1260);
    circle(-1316, 1316, 140);
    circle(-1120, 1260, 196);
    circle(-840, 1260, 140);
    circle(-560, 1260, 252);
    circle(-280, 1260, 112);
    circle(0, 1260, 196);
    circle(280, 1260, 112);
    circle(420, 1260, 84);
    circle(560, 1260, 196);
    circle(700, 1260, 84);
    circle(840, 1260, 112);
    circle(980, 1260, 112);
    circle(1120, 1260, 196);
    circle(1260, 1260, 140);
}

void lightning()
{
    glColor3f(0.88, 0.90, 0.93);
    rectangle(-644, 1260, -560, 1260, -840, 616, -980, 560);
    rectangle(-980, 560, -840, 616, -588, 616, -700, 560);
    triangle(-700, 560, -588, 616, -840, 0);
}


/*===========================
***********GHOST 2**********
*===========================*/

void ghost2()
{
    // hair 
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); //black
    circle(-980, -420, 112);
    circle(-700, -420, 112);
    triangle(-1092, -420, -980, -532, -1092, -532);
    triangle(-588, -420, -588, -532, -700, -532);
    rectangle(-1092, -532, -980, -532, -980, -616, -1092, -616);
    rectangle(-700, -532, -588, -532, -588, -616, -700, -616);
    rectangle(-1092, -616, -980, -616, -924, -672, -1092, -672);
    rectangle(-700, -616, -588, -616, -588, -672, -756, -672);
    rectangle(-1092, -672, -924, -672, -924, -980, -1092, -980);
    rectangle(-756, -672, -588, -672, -588, -980, -756, -980);

    //face 
    glColor3f(0.8, 0.8, 0.8); //light grey
    rectangle(-980, -532, -700, -532, -700, -616, -980, -616);
    rectangle(-980, -616, -700, -616, -812, -700, -868, -700);

    //mouth 1
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); //red
    circle(-840, -560, 112);
    //mouth 2
    glColor3f(0.8, 0.8, 0.8); //light grey
    triangle(-952, -532, -728, -532, -840, -616);
    // hair 1
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); //black
    rectangle(-980, -308, -700, -308, -700, -532, -980, -532);

    //cloth 
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); //red
    rectangle(-924, -672, -868, -700, -868, -896, -924, -868);
    rectangle(-868, -700, -812, -700, -812, -896, -868, -896);
    rectangle(-812, -700, -756, -672, -756, -868, -812, -896);
    rectangle(-1176, -700, -1092, -700, -1092, -812, -1176, -728);
    rectangle(-588, -700, -560, -700, -532, -756, -588, -812);

    //left leg 
    glColor3f(0.91, 0.90, 0.89); //darker light grey
    rectangle(-1316, -476, -1176, -560, -1260, -672, -1344, -644);
    rectangle(-1400, -560, -1316, -476, -1344, -644, -1400, -728);

    //right leg 
    glColor3f(0.91, 0.90, 0.89); //darker light grey
    rectangle(-504, -560, -392, -476, -392, -672, -448, -728);
    rectangle(-392, -476, -140, -1008, -224, -1092, -392, -672);
    rectangle(-140, -1008, -84, -1008, -84, -1092, -224, -1092);

    //left arm 
    glColor3f(0.8, 0.8, 0.8); //light grey
    rectangle(-1260, -560, -1092, -560, -1092, -700, -1176, -700);
    rectangle(-1260, -560, -1176, -700, -1288, -1176, -1372, -1092);
    rectangle(-1400, -1092, -1372, -1092, -1288, -1176, -1400, -1176);

    //right arm 
    glColor3f(0.8, 0.8, 0.8); //light grey
    rectangle(-588, -560, -448, -560, -560, -700, -588, -700);
    rectangle(-560, -700, -448, -560, -392, -1092, -476, -1176);
    rectangle(-392, -1092, -336, -1092, -336, -1176, -476, -1176);
}

/*===========================
**********MOVEMENTS *********
*===========================*/

void ghost2_move()
{
    // hair 
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); //black
    rectangle(-280, 700, 280, 700, 280, 420, -280, 420);
    circle(-280, 560, 140);
    circle(280, 560, 140);
    triangle(-420, 560, -280, 420, -420, 420);
    triangle(280, 420, 420, 560, 420, 420);
    rectangle(-420, 420, -280, 420, -280, 140, -420, 140);
    rectangle(280, 420, 420, 420, 420, 140, 280, 140);
    rectangle(-420, 140, -280, 140, -140, 56, -420, 56);
    rectangle(280, 140, 420, 140, 420, 84, 168, 84);
    rectangle(-420, 56, -140, 56, -140, -560, -420, -560);
    rectangle(168, 84, 420, 84, 420, -560, 168, -560);

    //cloth 
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); //red
    rectangle(-140, 56, -28, 0, -28, -420, -140, -364);
    rectangle(-28, 0, 28, 0, 28, -420, -28, -420);
    rectangle(28, 0, 168, 84, 168, -364, 28, -420);
    triangle(-700, -28, -420, -28, -420, -280);
    triangle(420, -28, 700, -28, 420, -280);

    //face 
    glColor3f(0.8, 0.8, 0.8); //light grey
    rectangle(-280, 420, 280, 420, 280, 140, -280, 140);
    rectangle(-280, 140, 280, 140, 28, 0, -28, 0);

    //eye
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); //black
    circle(-140, 336, 56);
    circle(140, 336, 56);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); //red
    circle(-140, 336, 14);
    circle(140, 336, 14);
    

    //mouth 
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); //red
    triangle(-224, 196, 224, 196, 0, 28);
    
    //left leg 
    glColor3f(0.91, 0.90, 0.89); //darker light grey
    rectangle(-924, 364, -616, 140, -700, -56, -980, 168);
    rectangle(-1400, 0, -924, 364, -980, 168, -1400, -252);
    //right leg 
    rectangle(560, 140, 784, 364, 868, 168, 700, -56);
    rectangle(784, 364, 1400, 56, 1400, -196, 868, 168);

    //left arm 
    glColor3f(0.8, 0.8, 0.8); //light grey
    rectangle(-840, 140, -420, 140, -420, -56, -700, -56);
    rectangle(-1232, -560, -840, 140, -700, -56, -1232, -728);
    rectangle(-1400, -560, -1232, -560, -1232, -728, -1400, -728);
    //right arm 
    rectangle(420, 140, 840, 140, 700, -56, 420, -56);
    rectangle(840, 140, 1260, -644, 1260, -812, 700, -56);
    rectangle(1260, -644, 1400, -644, 1400, -812, 1260, -812);
}

/*===========================
******DISPLAY FUNCTION*******
*===========================*/

void display1() //scene 1 with the ghost in front of the car (before lightning)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.12, 0.13, 0.12, 1.0); //background color - black
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_WIDTH, -SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    road();
    car();
    cloud();
    ghost2();

    glutSwapBuffers();

}

void display2() //scene 2 - first lightning
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.12, 0.13, 0.12, 1.0); //background color - black
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_WIDTH, -SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    road();
    car();
    cloud();
    ghost2();
    glColor3f(0.88, 0.90, 0.93);
    rectangle(-644, 1260, -560, 1260, -840, 616, -980, 560);

    glutSwapBuffers();

}

void display3() //scene 3 - second lightning
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.12, 0.13, 0.12, 1.0); //background color - black
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_WIDTH, -SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    road();
    car();
    cloud();
    ghost2();
    glColor3f(0.88, 0.90, 0.93);
    rectangle(-644, 1260, -560, 1260, -840, 616, -980, 560);
    rectangle(-980, 560, -840, 616, -588, 616, -700, 560);

    glutSwapBuffers();

}

void display4() //scene 4 - third or full lightning
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.12, 0.13, 0.12, 1.0); //background color - black
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_WIDTH, -SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    road();
    car();
    cloud();
    ghost2();
    lightning();

    glutSwapBuffers();

}

void display5() //scene 5 - lightning strike -> blinding Lily's eye
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.9, 0.89, 0.88, 1.0); //background color - black
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_WIDTH, -SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    glColor3f(0.91, 0.96, 0.93);
    road();
    //car
    //upper car body
    glColor3f(0.85, 0.8, 0.9); //blue
    rectangle(0, 280, 1120, 280, 1400, -140, -560, -140);
    //bottom car body
    rectangle(-840, -140, 1400, -140, 1400, -700, -840, -700);
    //front- window (window 1)
    glColor3f(0.9, 0.89, 0.88); //white
    triangle(-476, -140, -28, 196, -28, -140);
    rectangle(28, 196, 560, 196, 560, -140, 28, -140);
    rectangle(644, 196, 1120, 196, 1120, -140, 644, -140);
    //wheel
    circle(-420, -798, 196); //front wheel
    circle(1036, -798, 196); // back wheel

    glColor3f(0.91, 0.96, 0.93);
    cloud();
    lightning();

    glutSwapBuffers();

}

void display6() //scene 6 - after lightning
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.12, 0.13, 0.12, 1.0); //background color - black
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_WIDTH, -SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    road();
    car();
    cloud();

    glutSwapBuffers();

}

void display7() //last scene- ghost suddenly appeared right in front of Lily out of nowhere
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.12, 0.13, 0.12, 1.0); //background color - black
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_WIDTH, -SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    //objects / background
    road();
    car();
    cloud();
    ghost2_move();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void idle() {
    DWORD start = GetTickCount64();
    while (GetTickCount64() - start < 1000 / FPS);
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    if (x < 0 || x > SCREEN_WIDTH) dx *= -1;
    if (y < 0 || y > SCREEN_HEIGHT) dy *= -1;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void initGL() {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 0, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    glPointSize(10.0);
    glPointSize(10.0);
    glLineWidth(10.0);
}



/*===========================
***********MAIN**************
*===========================*/

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutCreateWindow("Outside Window");
    glutDisplayFunc(display1);
    glutReshapeWindow(1200, 1000);
    //glutTimerFunc(2000, timer, 0);

    glutIdleFunc(idle);
    glutTimerFunc(1000, MyTimerFunc, 0);
    srand(1);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    initGL();
    glutMainLoop();
}

void MyTimerFunc(int value)
{
    if (value == 0)
    {
        glutDisplayFunc(display1);
        glutIdleFunc(display1);
        glutTimerFunc(1000, MyTimerFunc, 1);
    }

    if (value == 1)
    {
        glutDisplayFunc(display2);
        glutIdleFunc(display2);
        glutTimerFunc(1000, MyTimerFunc, 2);
    }

    
    if (value == 2)
    {
        glutDisplayFunc(display3);
        glutIdleFunc(display3);
        glutTimerFunc(1000, MyTimerFunc, 2);
    }

    if (value == 3)
    {
        glutDisplayFunc(display4);
        glutIdleFunc(display4);
        glutTimerFunc(1000, MyTimerFunc, 2);
    }

    if (value == 4)
    {
        glutDisplayFunc(display5);
        glutIdleFunc(display5);
        glutTimerFunc(1000, MyTimerFunc, 2);
    }

    if (value == 5)
    {
        glutDisplayFunc(display6);
        glutIdleFunc(display6);
        glutTimerFunc(1000, MyTimerFunc, 2);
    }

    if (value == 6)
    {
        glutDisplayFunc(display7);
        glutIdleFunc(display7);
        glutTimerFunc(1000, MyTimerFunc, 2);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Im sorry, i made a silly mistake by not setting the right screen width and screen height, I can now run my code